# YOLOv3 convolutional layers count

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, yolo

I am really confused about the count of the convolutional layers exist in YOLOv3!

According to the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02767) they are using *darknet-**53*** and they don't mention any further details or addition to that structure!

However, according to the build of [AlexeyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) it is composed of **106** layers!
moreover, the *[towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/yolo-v3-object-detection-53fb7d3bfe6b)* website claims that the additional 53 layers are added for the detection process, but what does that really mean are the first 53 layers only for feature extraction then?

So my question is, what is the matter of these extra unmentioned-in-the-paper 53 layers? where did they come from? and why?

Answer (score 0):

Darknet-53 is the name of the extractor developed by Joseph Redmon et al., and it does indeed constitute the first 53 layers of YOLOv3. The next 53 layers are dedicated to resizing, concatenation and upsampling the input to prepare them for detection at three different scales at layer 82, 94 and 106 respectively. The first layer detects the largest objects, the second the ones in the middle, and the last layer all that remains (in theory at least).

I think the idea of this hierarchical structure is the further one moves into YOLOv3, the more high-level information it is able to extract.

Answer (score 0):

According to AlexeyAB (creator of very popular forked Darknet version) https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/darknet/9WppEzRouMU (This link is deprecated somehow)

Yolo has 
**75 cnn-layers (convolutional layers)** + 31 other layers (shortcut, route, upsample, yolo) = 106 layers in total.

You can count the total of CNN layer in cfg file, there are 75. Also remember that Yolo V3 does detection at 3 different scales, which are at layer 82,94,106.